# How to smoothly display opponents in realtime multiplayer game

Tags: libgdx, networking, multiplayer

I'm implementing a small-scale multiplayer racing game. As of right now, the client sends updates to the opponents on a fixed interval (or as fast as possible), containing location on the map etc. Each client will then reposition that opponent on that location.

Obviously, this will not run smoothly due to network lag. The vehicles will jump between each location.

One solution for this would be to include the speed and direction with each update-package, and then keep the vehicle running as that until next update, and then animate a movement to the new position. Repeat.

This only works if the player drives predictably, e.g not reversing after update etc. It is not important that the sync is exact, but should be pretty close to the reality location-wise.

How to smoothly show opponents in a realtime multiplayer game?

Comment: The game is using `LibGDX` and AppWarp; if that matters. Generic answers are fine.

Comment: That question has quite massive scope. There are many ways this can be done.

Comment: @Almo I'm unsure how to make it more focused, please feel free to edit it if you have an idea how. My solution feels quite stupid; I'm simply looking for smarter ways which produce better results.

Comment: You're better off reading about this topic. A google search should bring up various blogs and developers talking about how they dealt with this. Or you could grab the source to an engine like Quake 3 and see how they actually did it. This is a Q&A site, designed for well-defined questions with well-defined answers.

Comment: A single answer cannot cover something this broad. You want to be looking at entity interpolation, extrapolation, and dead reckoning.